# Stuck on getting access token from Twitter API using Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm integrating Login with Twitter on my website and I'm totally stuck right now.
I'm following this guide: (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) and is doing it in Scala using the Play framework.

I've read about a lot of people getting the 401 Unauthorized error all the time and so did I earlier on "Step 1: Obtaining a request token" but I solved it by not passing the oauth_callback_url which I found out here: https://github.com/cyrus7580/twitter_api_examples/blob/master/src/SampleTwitterRequests.java

Now my problem is on "Step 3: Converting the request token to an access token", the last step... The problem is when I'm doing the POST to the oauth/access_token endpoint. I get the 401 - Unauthorized - Invalid request token.

I got both the Request token and the verifier from "Step 2".

My code looks like this for step 3:

```
val token = "R6qe*********************PbTAvlHw" //Got this from step 2
val verifier = "s1jWnOz********************eJEU" //Got this from step 2
val twitterConsumerKey = "iLRU**********uQ"
val twitterConsumerSecret = "DsdGs***********dgfd2"
val signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1"
val version = "1.0"

val nonce = getNonce() //method return a 32character random nonce (worked in step 2)
val timeStamp = (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000).toString

    val parameterString:String = 
       "oauth_consumer_key=" + twitterConsumerKey + 
      "&oauth_nonce=" + nonce + 
      "&oauth_signature_method=" + signatureMethod + 
      "&oauth_timestamp=" + timeStamp +
      "&oauth_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8") +
      "&oauth_version=" + version  

      val baseString:String = "POST&"+ URLEncoder.encode("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "UTF-8")+"&"+ URLEncoder.encode(parameterString2, "UTF-8")   
      val signature = getSignature(twitterConsumerSecret, baseString, "HmacSHA1")

      val data = "OAuth " +
          "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + twitterConsumerKey +
      "\",oauth_signature_method=\"" + signatureMethod +
      "\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + timeStamp +
      "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce +
      "\",oauth_version=\"" + version + 
      "\",oauth_signature=\"" + signature + 
      "\",oauth_token=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8") + "\""


      Async{
      WS.url("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token").withHeaders("Authorization" -> data).post("oauth_verifier="+URLEncoder.encode(verifier, "UTF-8")).map(response => {
        Logger.info(response.body.toString()) //Invalid request token
        Logger.info(response.status.toString) //401
        Logger.info(response.statusText) //Unauthorized
        Ok("Welcome")
      })
    }
```

The getSignature(twitterConsumerSecret, baseString, "HmacSHA1") looks like this:

```
def getSignature(consumerSecret:String, baseString:String, algorithm:String):String = {
  val key:String = consumerSecret + "&"
  val signingKey:SecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algorithm)

  try{
  var mac: Mac = null;
      mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
      mac.init(signingKey);

  val rawHmac:Array[Byte] = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());

  val oauth_signature:String =  new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(rawHmac)
  val oauth_signatureFinal:String = URLEncoder.encode(oauth_signature, "UTF-8")

  return oauth_signatureFinal
  }
}
```

I hope somebody have any thoughts on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `oauth_verifier`

When the user returns from Twitter after they've click "yes I approve of this app", Twitter will post back to you `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`.

To get an access token, you should add to `parameterString` somewhere the `oauth_verifier` value. So, pretending that oauthVerifier is the value from Twitter, `parameterString` somewhere should be added:

`parameterString = parameterString + "&oauth_verifier=" + oauthVerifier`

I also noticed that this line uses parameterString2, not parameterString... I never saw parameterString2 defined

```
val baseString:String = "POST&"+URLEncoder.encode("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode(parameterString2, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: I did see now that I had the wrong URL in the code example here at SO. "Async{
      WS.url("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token")"

Should ofcourse be(and is in my code):

"Async{
      WS.url("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token")"

I'll have a look at my code again and get back to here with the result. EDIT: the parameterString2 is also a typo here at SO, in my code they both are named parameterString :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! "parameterString = parameterString + "&oauth_verifier=" + oauthVerifier" was the answer! I tought, and i looked so in the twitter guide, that you should pass the verifier in the body.. Now i pass it in the header and it works flawless. Thank you!

Comment: i thought the parameter string needed to be in alphabetical (lexical) order. Meaning that oauth_verifier should be second last not last...